# Converting dates by AWK

Tags: date, awk, type-conversion

I have a date file of too much records containing specific date format like the following 5th column:

```
9010146679      20170129        26079   2/6/2017        2/11/2017       1002    
9010149451      20170129        26079   2/6/2017        2/13/2017       1002    
9010149451      20170129        24079   2/6/2017        2/14/2017       1005    
9010156092      20170129        26079   2/6/2017        2/15/2017       1002
```

I want to change 5th column date format to the format in second column.
Logically, what I mean is something like below:

```
awk '{for (i=11;i<=15;i++) { if (5$=="2/i/2017") sub("2/i/2017","201702i") }}' file.txt
```

I can't find the proper syntax. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk '{split( $5, T, /\//); $5 = T[3] sprintf( "%0.2d", T[1]) sprintf( "%0.2d", T[2]); print}' YourFile
```

using direct info from field 5 ($5) put into an array (split) and rewrite using 2 digit format for month and day (the sprintf) in new "reversed" format

i made it for every day number, not only 11 -> 15 assuming you give a sample of and not a constraint